# Flutter: logger

Tags: logging, dart, flutter

I'm using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/logging, but it doesn't display anything to my log. This is my code:

```
class Test {

  final Logger log = new Logger('testLogger');

  Future<String> join() async {
    try {
      return await func();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
        log.severe('access denied!');
        return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: In Flutter it would be better to use `debugPrint()` instead of `print()` - updated my answer.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html it just works a bit better with Android devices which might drop log output if rate is too high.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register a log reporter.

From https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/logging

```
main() {
  Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {
    debugPrint('${rec.level.name}: ${rec.time}: ${rec.message}');
  });
  runApp(...);
}
```

You can have log reporters that write to a file or to some logging server, ...

Comment: How to have a log reporter that write to a file?

Comment: Just open a file and write to it, instead of `debugPrint(...)`

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'm am relatively new to flutter, so I'll have to check the documentation of the logging package to see how to do this. Do you mind if I ask you for an example?

Comment: That's not related to the logging package, that's only related to opening a file, writing to it, and closing it again. All that's logging related is `Logger.root.onRecord` and the passed parameter `LogRecord rec`. `listen` is `Stream` related, and the part inside `{...}` is just your custom code where you can handle the `LogRecord` and do with it what you want.

Comment: Great! I get it, so thanks a lot. I'll be checking that out. Dankeschön!